# ifs environment variable is not inherited

Tags: linux, environment-variables

In Unix the IFS variable was often used to subvert system integrity.
How it was fixed?
The only answer I found is in wikipedia page 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_field_separator  which says:
"This has been fixed by making the shells not inherit the IFS variable."

I can verify it in my Debian 6 system:

```
$ export IFS=/  
$ printf "%s" "$IFS" | od -bc
0000000 057
          /
0000001
$ bash
bash-$ printf "%s" "$IFS" | od -bc
0000000 040 011 012                     # default values
             \t  \n
0000003
bash-$ exit
exit
$ 
$ printf "%s" "$IFS" | od -bc
0000000 057
          /
0000001
$
```

It's enough to avoid privilege escalation?  How can I use IFS to break absolute pathnames inside system() calls?

Answer (score 0):

Either the executable making the system() call has already turned the pathname into components (which is what I think you mean by "break") and used $IFS elements (usually space) to separate the components, or the shell script being invoked by system() will manipulate $IFS itself.

Example of the executable breaking up the path:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_TOKENS 100
#define COMMAND "echo "
int main() {
  char path[]       = "/file/system/path";
  char *delims      = "/";
  int  i            = 1;
  char *token;
  char broken_path[sizeof(COMMAND) + sizeof(path) + 3*MAX_TOKENS];

  strcpy(broken_path, COMMAND);

  token = strtok(path, delims);
  while(i < MAX_TOKENS) {
    if (token == NULL) {
      break;
    }
    strcat(broken_path,"'");
    strcat(broken_path, token);
    strcat(broken_path, "' ");
    token = strtok(NULL, delims);
  }
  printf("%s\n", broken_path);
  return system(broken_path);
}
```

An example of the invoked script "breaking" the path:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_TOKENS 100
#define COMMAND "./my_script.sh "
int main() {
  char path[]       = "/file/system/path";
  char broken_path[sizeof(COMMAND) + sizeof(path) + 2];

  sprintf(broken_path, "%s %s", COMMAND, path);
  return system(broken_path);
}
```

...with ./my_script.sh containing

```
#!/bin/sh
oldIFS="$IFS"
declare -a elements
IFS="/"
# break $1 into path components
elements=($1)
echo "${elements[@]}"
IFS="$oldIFS"
```